# jQuery carousel slider with auto widths and direction based dynamic alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel

I'm looking for a responsive jQuery carousel content slider with custom/different/auto widths that scrolls by one item and aligns based on the direction.
For example if the user clicks on the right navigation arrow it should slide slide by one item to the first not fully visible item and it should be aligned to the right end of the viewport and if the user clicks on the left navigation arrow the slider should slide by one item to the first not fully visible item on the left end of the viewport and align it to the same end.

I've spent a couple of days searching for such carousel but so far with no luck. Some of the sliders/carousels I've looked into are: LightSlider, slick, Flickity, Glide, UIkit (getuikit) and more. I've even written a new navigation logic for Flickity using its API which almost does it but it's buggy and with a lot of animation problems.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#autoWidth').lightSlider({
        autoWidth:true,
        loop:false,
        pager:false,
        prevHtml:'<',
        nextHtml:'>',
        onSliderLoad: function() {
            $('#autoWidth').removeClass('cS-hidden');
        } 
    }).goToSlide(6);
});
```

As a behavioural example open this link http://codepen.io/matthewd/pen/BKvjWM, click the left and then the right arrow.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: I would have thought the slick 'variable width' demo matches that codepen almost perfectly - http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Yes alomst. Actually all uppermentioned plugins have the same behaviour but they do not align dynamically based on the direction. They have either center, left or right (Flickity) alignment.

Comment: Since I was already using UIkit (getuikit.com), I ended up "extending" their original [Slider component](http://getuikit.com/docs/slider.html) with a JS class of my own which uses the slider API. Not the prettiest solution but does the job.